# Editing JavaScript Arrays then .map()ing them to another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to be able to take strings or numbers from one Array and then abbreviate them to their first two or three letters/numbers and then .map() them to another Array.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have already tried, otherwise as is asking for code is considered off topic.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution can abbreviate both numbers and strings.

```
const maxLength = 2;
const theArray = [12345, 7736251, "abcdef", "foo", "baaaaar"];
const theResult = theArray.map(entry => String(entry).slice(0, maxLength));
```

If you'd like to preserve the type, I can modify the code to account for it.

Comment: Thank you this worked great.